# How can I make this a correct test cases list?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am doing this programming problem to run without entering numbers every time. I want to make it run with the answer that I have entered in the testCase.
https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=945

```
class TestCase:
  def __init__(self,input,output):
    self.input = input
    self.output = output
    
testCases = []
t1 = TestCase((3, 3, (0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), 3), "NOT BICOLORABLE.")
'''t2 = TestCase(('2', '0 1','1 2', '9'), 'BICOLORABLE.')
t3 = TestCase(('9', '8', '0 1', '0 2', '0 3', '0 4', '0 5', '0 6', '0 7', '0 8', '0'), 'BICOLORABLE.')'''
testCases.append(t1)
#testCases.append(t2)
#testCases.append(t3)
```

and here is the code (if there is any mistake please correct me.)

```
def solve(input):
  while True:
    try:
      num_v = int(input())
      num_e = int(input())
    
      e = {i: [] for i in range(num_v)}

      for i in range(num_e):
        line = input().split()
        src, dst = int(line[0]), int(line[1])
        e[src].append(dst)
        e[dst].append(src)

      seen = {} # v_id: int: is_0_colored: boolean
    
      bicolorable = True
      output = bicolorable
      v_id = 0
      v_processor = [(0, True)]

      while v_id < len(v_processor):
        p = v_processor[v_id]
        seen[p[0]] = p[1]

        for dst in e[p[0]]:
          if dst in seen:
            if p[1] == seen[dst]:
              bicolorable = False
              break
          else: 
            v_processor.append((dst, not p[1]))
  
        v_id += 1
      
        if not bicolorable:
          break

      if bicolorable:
        print("BICOLORABLE.")
      else:
        print("NOT BICOLORABLE.")
    except(EOFError):
      break

  return output
```

And this is the test script to run the code.

```
# Test script

for i in range(len(testCases)):
  print(testCases[i].input)
  print("*** Testing program with test case no.", i)
  %timeit global output; output=solve(testCases[i].input)

  if output==testCases[i].output:
    print("Okay")
  else:
    print("Incorrect!\nExpected output:", testCases[i].output)
    print("Actual output:", output)
```

My problem is that when I run it shows TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable. I don't understand what I did wrong and I have tried many time to change the way of how the input numbers is in the testCase but still not work.

```
(3, 3, (0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), 3)
*** Testing program with test case no. 0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-f3a3fe984f4b> in <module>()
      4   print(testCases[i].input)
      5   print("*** Testing program with test case no.", i)
----> 6   get_ipython().magic('timeit global output; output=solve(testCases[i].input)')
      7 
      8   if output==testCases[i].output:

5 frames
<decorator-gen-52> in timeit(self, line, cell)

<magic-timeit> in inner(_it, _timer)

<ipython-input-35-20bd60aca820> in solve(input)
      5   while True:
      6     try:
----> 7       num_v = int(input())
      8       num_e = int(input())
      9 

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBt7p.png)

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Your function argument is called `input` - which overwrites the name of the inbuilt function `input` that you're trying to call.